# Converting numerics with COMMAw,d

Tags: sas

I am following the [SAS help page](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000200667.htm) and was trying to achieve the same results as in the examples to the bottom of the page.
My code:

```
data _null_;
    test=23451.23;
    result=input(test,comma10.2);
    put 'this should be:' result;
run;
```

with the output in the Log

```
this should be:23451
```

while it should be 23,451.23. There are no errors nor helpful notes nor warnings.

When I am not using the input function, it delivers the correct result

```
data _null_;
        test=23451.23;
        format test comma10.2;
        put 'this should be:' test;
run;
```

What is happening here? Is it not possible to combine **input** and **COMMAw,d**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Formats are used to convert values into strings.  Informats are used to convert strings into values.  You use formats with PUT and FORMAT statements or PUT() function.  You use informats with INPUT and INFORMAT statements or INPUT() function.

So the `INPUT()` function needs a character string as the first argument, but you have given it a number.  **Notice that SAS will put a NOTE in the log saying that it had to convert numbers to characters.**  SAS will use the `BEST12.` format to convert so your number, `23451.23`, becomes the 12 character string `'    23451.23'`.  Then when the `INPUT()` function uses the `COMMA10.2` informat it reads only the first 10 characters and you miss the decimal digits.  Note that not only should the width be longer but you should NOT have included a value after the decimal point in the informat.  If your informat had an even smaller width you would have missed the decimal point and SAS would have implied one (divided the integer value by 100).

If you want your numbers to be displayed in a particular way then just attach the desired format to the variable. You could just add the format specification to the `PUT` statement.

```
put test= comma10.2 ;
```

Or attach the format to the variable using the `FORMAT` statement.

```
format test comma10.2;
```

If you want to convert your number into a character string then use the `PUT()` function

```
char_result = put(test,comma10.2);
```

or `PUTN()` function.

```
char_result = putn(test,'comma10.2');
```

Comment: In your comment you say that there is no difference between `23,451.23` and `23451.23` which I'd ofc agree, but SAS itself would only take `23451.23` as a default numeric, right? When it comes to the `input()` function, you're right, I don't want to convert but rather display the numeric differently. Still, why would there not be at least an error/warning while giving me the clearly wrong output `23451` without decimals? Just bad compiler (and user) behaviour?

Comment: Right, you cannot use commas in numeric literals in your code.  And if you have the commas in text data that you are reading with `INPUT` statement or `INPUT()` function then you need to use the right `INFORMAT` to convert text with commas into values.  You can use a number of `FORMAT` specifications for displaying the value, but that does not change the actual value, just how it is displayed as text.  In most places if you have not attached a format then SAS will use `BEST12.` to display numbers.

Comment: I will update the answer to explain why using a width of `10` with `2` implied decimal places is wrong for reading the character string that SAS will convert your number into.

Answer (score 1):

Use Put statement:

```
data _null_;
   test=23451.23;
   result=put(test,comma10.2);
   put 'this should be:' result;
run;
```

> this should be:23,451.23

---

[Link](https://blogs.sas.com/content/sgf/2015/05/01/converting-variable-types-do-i-use-put-or-input/) to explained diff's between functions.
Table from page:

```
+---------------------------+-------------------+------------+---------------------+-----------------+
|       Function Call       |      Raw Type     |  Raw Value |    Returned Type    |  Returned Value |
+---------------------------+-------------------+------------+---------------------+-----------------+
| A  PUT(name, $10.);       | char, char format | ‘Richard’  | char always         | ‘Richard   ’    |
| B  PUT(age, 4.);          | num, num format   | 30         | char always         | ‘  30’          |
| C  PUT(name, $nickname.); | char, char format | ‘Richard’  | char always         | ‘Rick’          |
| D  INPUT(agechar, 4.);    | char always       | ‘30’       | num, num informat   | 30              |
| E  INPUT(agechar, $4.);   | char always       | ‘30’       | char, char informat | ‘  30’          |
| F  INPUT(cost,comma7.);   | char always       | ‘100,541’  | num, num informat   | 100541          |
+---------------------------+-------------------+------------+---------------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: Thx for the link! Gonna look into it.

Comment: One problem here: PUT() creates a character variable...I actually want to keep it as a numeric and following the link you've provided, I am supposed to take the INPUT() which doesn't work. Any idea?

Comment: If you want it is as a number then you don't need to convert it.  There is no difference between the number meant by `23,451.23` and the number meant by `23451.23`. You can attach a format to the variable to tell SAS to display the number in different ways.